# How to add a Word Document as an email attachment for SingleEmailMessage Class

Tags: apex, trigger, email

I am creating an email that triggers when the opportunity moves into the proposal stage. The email delivered will have the following information along with the word document attachment:

[image: rd]

I see in the SingleEmailMessage methods [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) that there is a method for attaching files to the email.

```
setEntityAttachments(ids)
```

My question is that I am not entirely sure what IDs this accepts as parameters. Is it files or documents? Both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) you mentioned, the object types are clearly stated for `setEntityAttachments()`

> Optional. Array of IDs of Document, ContentVersion, or Attachment
>   items to attach to the email.

where `ContentVersion` is a File.